# Best approach to authorize woo commerce API

Tags: angular, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am developing a SPA which will allow customers to customize a product - kind of complex product wizard. As I'm a front-end developer I assumed that using Wordpress and Woocommerce will be an easy win. Unfortunately I've got a problem with authorizing my app in Woocommerce API.

I know that there are several ways to do it: basic authentication, JWT or oAuth. All of these approaches need to provide a user credentials (login and password). is there any possible way to handle this without exposing them on front-end side? If not, which is the best way to authorize my app in Woocommerce API, assuming that it needs to customize a product, make an order, handle payments and give ability to create a user account inside a store.

Comment: Have you looked at the Gravity forms plugin for Woocommerce? It offers customization of products. If it doesn't do what you need it to, their methods may help answer your question.

Comment: Question was related rather to app authorization, not product customization.

Comment: I also studied the WooCommerce REST API and it seemed to me that the API was designed for server to server use and not front-end to server use. One other reason I believe this is the 4 client libraries are for Node.js, Python, PHP and Ruby - all server side languages, there is no JavaScript client library. The credentials on the front-end should be buyer  credentials not the REST API credentials. I am not an expert on the Woo REST API and this is just my opinion after some studying.

Comment: Yeap I've figured it out as well. Probably putting ex. node.js or php in the middle would be a good solution. What do you think?

Comment: That was my thinking also. Will your solution be GPL? I have an interest in a solution to this problem,

Comment: I can make this part public. But still need some time to develop it. If I will success I'll let you know. Still I don't know how to handle a problem with buyer credentials. I don't want to force my clients to create accounts. Is a one common account for a whole app a good solution? If not, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: WooCommerce allows non-logged-in buyers to populate a cart by creating a temporary buyer based on session data (Cookies and session storage).

Comment: Could you provide my any link which will get my closer to this issue?

Comment: @user1749571, have you tried the [Woocommerce APi Authentication endpoint](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication)?